# Loading a html file through angular's ui-router using templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using the Angular UI-Router to declare states. My states are set up correctly and angular is working on my page but the template html file is not being loaded correctly. When I do

```
template: 'template: 'js/timer/timer.template.html'
```

in my controller, the text (the path above) is rendered as expected but when I switch it to

```
templateUrl: 'js/timer/timer.template.html',
```

the timer.template.html file is not being rendered. What does happen though is my index.html file seems to be loaded twice. Once as expected and a second time where it is copied and injected into the `<ui-view> </ui-view>`
here is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base href="/">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/angular-ui-router@0.3.2/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"> </script>
        <script src="main.js"> </script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app='PomodoroTimer'>
        <ui-view> </ui-view>
        <p>1+2={{1+2}}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I go to localhost:1337/timer (the state that I have set up) this index.html file seems to get twice, once as expected and then again in the ui-view, 1+2=3 is displayed twice.

This is my timer.state.js file. I have tried using different paths but nothing seems to point to the right html file.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('timer', {
        url: '/timer',
        templateUrl: 'js/timer/timer.template.html',
        controller: 'TimerCtrl'
    });
});
```

Is there something I'm missing about UI-Router or templateUrl or something I don't have set up correctly? I'm using express to handle routing but just send all requests to /* to the index.html file so that UI-Router can take over. Do I have to serve the template html files statically through express like you would for css files?

Here is the timer.template.html where timerMessage is defined on the `$scope` of the controller

```
<p>This is the timer state and message is: {{timerMessage}}</p>
```

Here's the github link: [github.com/sbernheim4/pomodoro-timer](http://github.com/sbernheim4/pomodoro-timer)

Comment: do you get your template when you hit `localhost:1337/js/timer/timer.template.html` ?

Comment: No I don't, the index.html file is loaded and the `1+2=3` is displayed

Comment: right. so that's your problem. You need to change your server or build process such that the url you are specifying for a template actually loads the template

Comment: Got it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your last paragraph gave away what is happening.
Node can't match the path `js/timer/timer.template.html` to any route so the catch all gets executed (returns the index instead of the actual file).

Here's an example of how to configure Express for html5mode:

```
//Look for statics first - this is important!
var oneHour = 3600 * 1000;
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {maxAge: oneHour}));
//Return the index for any other GET request
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: path.join(__dirname, 'public')});
});
```

So yes, basically you have to serve the templates as you do with js and css files.

Comment: Got it. But then what should I do then if I ever have a bunch of folders each containing a state, controller and template html file, do I need to serve each of them up statically or is it better to put all my html files in one folder separate from their controllers and state js files

Comment: The example above works recursively so any directory and files nested in `/public` will be statically exported.